# How To Make Multi-view Apps?

Tags: iphone

I learn x-code first time. X-code is very complicated!

Would you tell me how to make multi-view apps?

(Step by step)

Comment: What do you mean by "multi-view" app?  One that has a tab bar for different views?  A navigation view that lets you drill down to other views?  A utility application that lets you flip over a view to expose another?  Each of these will require different explanations.

Answer (score 4):

I created a step by step guideline to create a multiview application here: [Multiview iPhone.pdf](http://www.box.net/shared/43diru43su)

Michael Tuszynski's vimeo tutorial (http://vimeo.com/8930397) is helpful but has some flaws (like creating view instances whenever switching)

Answer (score 3):

apple does an excellent job with their documentation.  There is a TON of reference material that answers your question. they provide step by step guides for building apps with multiple views:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/navigation/index.html?section=Resource+Types&topic=Getting+Started

Answer (score 0):

Personally I don't like Apple's documentation because it almost seems to assume that you already code for cocoa on os x.

The easiest way to create a multi-view app is to start a new Tab Bar Controller based application using the template, then drag however many View Controllers you want onto the tab bar controller icon. You can set set the icons and titles on their navigation items and just design and code the view controllers just like you would if each view controller were the only one, except that you probably want to connect them somehow to some shared resource.

Check out the book Beginning iPhone 3 Development as it has excellent step-by-step tutorials on how to do several kinds of multi-view applications. It's well worth the money especially if you get it from a discount book store online or something.

Comment: Please add author / publisher info for that book.

Comment: Here's the info: http://www.amazon.com/Beginning-iPhone-Development-Exploring-SDK/dp/1430224592/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1262907389&sr=8-1 Pretty damn impressive rating from customers.

Answer (score 0):

Apress Beginning iPhone 3 Development Exploring the iPhone SDK Jul.2009, By Dave and Jeff. They have given a wonderful tutorial for many types of applications including multiview apps